# How to replace HTML images with GatsbyJS responsive images?

Tags: reactjs, image, gatsby, directus

I am querying data from the Directus CMS in GatsbyJS using the [Directus 7 source](https://github.com/Jonesus/gatsby-source-directus7) like so:

```
query {
  allDirectusBlog {
    edges {
      node {
        name
        body
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My problem is that `body` is actually raw HTML with image tags pointing to my Directus server. Which is normally fine, however these images are extremely large and take a fair amount of time to load even over WiFi. Is there a way to replace these `<img>` tags with Gatsby responsive images at build time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've create a function using `html-react-parser` with the post content of WordPress to replace all img with  of Gatsby and the image provide in the `static` folder.

If you want a way to do that, this is a part of my code that you'll be able to adapte for your project (this is a WIP function, but work well)

```
export const ParsePostContentHTML = dataContent => {

    let indexKeyImg = 234;

    const ParsedHTML = Parse(dataContent, {
        replace: function(domNode) {
            if(domNode.name === 'img') {

                const fluidImg = data.allWordpressWpMedia.edges.filter(media => {
                    return media.node.source_url === domNode.attribs.src
                })

                if(fluidImg.length > 0) {
                    let srcMedia = (fluidImg[0].node.localFile.childImageSharp)
                        ? fluidImg[0].node.localFile.childImageSharp.fluid
                        : fluidImg[0].node.localFile.publicURL

                    indexKeyImg++

                    if(fluidImg[0].node.localFile.childImageSharp) {
                        return (
                            <Img
                                key={indexKeyImg}
                                fluid={srcMedia}
                                className={`${domNode.attribs.class} gatsby-rendered-img`}
                                alt={fluidImg[0].node.alt_text}
                            />
                        )
                    } else {
                        return (
                            <img
                                key={indexKeyImg}
                                src={srcMedia}
                                className={`${domNode.attribs.class} gatsby-rendered-img`}
                                alt={fluidImg[0].node.alt_text}
                            />
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })

    return ParsedHTML
}
```

You just have to import this function in your components/template and using it with `ParsePostContentHTML(YourPostContent)`

Hope that help you!

Comment: Thank you for your response! I might look into writing a Gatsby transformer for this sort of thing, would you mind if I used some of that code?

Comment: (Sorry, I can't upvote because of my reputation. I haven't done much yet)

Comment: @somebody0 no problem, you can use all of them if you want!